# How to umount usb drive?

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, dd, umount

I am a newbie Linux User

I wrote a Lubuntu image to my 8GB usb drive, and made it bootable, using the `dd` command.

After that I wanted to format it or make it `umount` but when I plug it to my PC I face this error:

```
Unable to access "Lubuntu 17.04 amd64"

Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/moji/Lubuntu 17.04 amd64: Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o 
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500"
"/dev/sdb1" "/media/moji/Lubuntu 17.04 amd64"' exited with non-zero exit status 32:
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: 1. Did the USB drive work as a USB boot drive with Lubuntu? 2. Do you want to use the USB drive for another purpose now? You can use mkusb to manage USB drives (and do several tasks). See more details at this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/962727/startup-disk-creator-in-lubuntu-16-04-making-usb-read-only-no-persistent-storag/962754#962754

Answer (score -1):

You can use graphical UI tool for making bootable USB flash drives as well as format to FAT32 EXT4 or NTFS, You will get "USB Image writer" & "USB Stick Formatter" just download  from Mint repositroy and install. Link below
http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mintstick/

Comment: @DavidFoerster Questions that are about Mint and not Ubuntu are off-topic. *Answers* can never be off-topic, though they can sometimes fail to answer the question they are posted on. Do you think this doesn't answer the question that was asked here? Mintstick is not just for making flash drives for running/installing Mint. At least according to this answer, it can be used to format drives flash drives with FAT32, ext4, and NTFS filesystems too. [Mintstick seems to install and run fine on Ubuntu.](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/mintstick-on-16-04/4735/7) Do you have reason to think it doesn't?

Comment: @EliahKagan: Fair enough. I though earlier that the answer assumed that OP has Mint repositories set up. I agree that installations of individual packages from the Mint repositories are and should be fair game here as long as they don't depend on anything specific to Mint.

Comment: Linux Mint is Ubuntu underneath. There are NO Mint specific dependencies, it works just fine on Ubuntu. And I quite "I am a newbie Linux User", so in this case mintsick is more suitable than dd. Also You can download any Linux Disro Image as you like, and make bootble USB flash drive with that image.